# gets() function in C input in an array

Tags: c, newline, gets

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    char a[10][100];
    printf("\n Enter the no. of strings:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("\n enter the %d numbers:",n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\n %d",i);

        gets(a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
        {
            puts(a[i]);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

If `n = 3` then it takes only two strings at index `1` and `2` it skips `0`, why doesn't it take input at `0` ?

Here `a` is my array of strings.

Comment: `gets` is a function that is impossible to use correctly. As such, it's been removed from the latest C standard. Using it is a bug. Please consider using `fgets` instead.

Comment: Because the `scanf` before it leaves a `\n` in the input buffer and `gets` reads it in the first iteration. BTW, [**Never use `gets`**. It is dangerous!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for wrong behavior is that `scanf` does not read the **ENTER** which is necessary to confirm the input of `n`. If you add `dummy` call of `gets` it does:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    char a[10][100];
    printf("\n Enter the no. of strings:");
    scanf("%d",&n); gets(a[0]);

    printf("\n enter the %d numbers:",n);

    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        printf("\n %d",i);

        gets(a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        {
            puts(a[i]);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Please `diff` my version with the original one. I did fix another issue in the output loop.

Comment: Thanks !It worked for me